# Passing empty props changes the Button color in ButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a customized `IconButton` element with `ButtonGroup`.

While passing an empty props, the color and hover shape of element is also changed. I want to know why did this happen? For me, an `HOC` shouldn't have different render effect with an empty prop passed.

I hosted a [minimal environment with GitHub Pages](https://pablion.github.io/pablion-questions/MUI_PCS). The question is shown on the second and third chapter.

[image: customized component without passing "{...props}"]

Using a new customized component.

Misbehavior: buttons are white and not in group.
See the hover highlight of second and third "G"
The component is based on `IconButton` without passing `{...props}`.

[image: customized component with {...props}.]

Using a new customized component. All good.

The component is also based on `IconButton` but passing `{...props}`.
Although the props is not passed, hence should be empty(?).
Maybe `useStyles` changed color, but the hover background shape is changed too.

Also I made a [related issue on official repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28899), and in my [Learning note](https://github.com/Pablion/Pablion/wiki/MUI-%28aka-Material-UI%29-learning-note#question-howwhy-does-the-props-affects-the-style-on-buttongroup-and-iconbutton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the opposite, if you don't pass the props to `IconButton`:

```
function IconButtonWrapper(props /* unused props */) {
  return (
    <IconButton>
      <DeleteIcon />
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

Then no styles are applied and the `IconButton` appears in plain white, so nothing changes.

> Although the props is not passed

The props are passed automatically from the `ButtonGroup`, even if you don't pass anything. The way it works is that `ButtonGroup` [clones](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/ea22ca9c340f01c3510a60285a9564edcbd2fcc2/packages/mui-material/src/ButtonGroup/ButtonGroup.js#L227-L237) the child component and pass its own set of props to them, so when you don't pass anything yourself like this:

```
<ButtonGroup variant="contained">
  <IconButtonWrapper />
  <IconButtonWrapper />
  <IconButtonWrapper />
</ButtonGroup>
```

The child component still has props provided by the parent, you can see it by logging the props:

```
function IconButtonWrapper(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <IconButton {...props}>
      <DeleteIcon />
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This explains my question. Now you made it very clear and I'm feeling stupid asking this. Maybe I was confused by myself before. Maybe I can edit the question and add all the related things here?

Comment: Also, can I link your answer to my sandbox page?

Comment: @Pablion don't feel bad, no one knows everything, I also only know about it after you asked this question. And yes you can.

Comment: I actually want to ask, if I should make 4 separated questions? Or I should ask all questions here? I think making 4 separated ones is clearer.

Comment: @Pablion making 4 questions in the same post will probably get your question closed with the 'require more clarity' reason, so most of the time it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thank for the advice. As you can see I'm very new here.